# Why does the FireFoxDriver not use the System.setProperty command in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Why do we need `System.setProperty` in the selenium webdriver command line for browsers other than FireFox?

what is the logic behind it?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium provides native support to Firefox. As per the document,

`Controls the Firefox browser using a Firefox plugin. The Firefox Profile that is used is stripped down from what is installed on the machine to only include the Selenium WebDriver.xpi (plugin).`

Whereas, Chrome and IE works differently,

Chrome driver :
`WebDriver works with Chrome through the chromedriver binary (found on the chromium project’s download page). You need to have both chromedriver and a version of chrome browser installed. chromedriver needs to be placed somewhere on your system’s path in order for WebDriver to automatically discover it. The Chrome browser itself is discovered by chromedriver in the default installation path.`

IE works only with windows, 
`This driver is controlled by a .dll and is thus only available on Windows OS. Each Selenium release has its core functionality tested against versions 6, 7 and 8 on XP, and 9 on Windows7.`

You can refer the document for better understanding [Selenium Document](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)